# RegEx Expression

Tags: .net, regex

I am getting data from a CSV File that looks like this:

```
Rob^,
Blah,
Blah,
Fail,
Fail,
Bob^,
Stuff,
Stuff,
Stuff,
Sam^,
Stuff,
Stuff
```

What I am trying to do is group everything that is between Rob^ and Bob^. So far my Regex looks like `\w+\^(,\n\w+)+` but Bob is getting selected. I have attempted at using look aheads but I haven't had any success. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\w+\^,\n(\w+,?\n)+
```

By moving the `,\n` to the end of the group it prevents you from matching lines with a `^` in them, the `,?` is necessary for the very last line in the file, since it does not contain a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Rob\^((.|\n)*)Bob\^
```

Everything between Rob^ and Bob^ is in the first group